# Is there a signal safe alternative to localtime_r()?

Tags: signals, localtime

We've got some code to do crawl the stack, and it's very handy to be able to dump the current time when we do so.  Unfortunately, while the `localtime_r()` function is reentrant, it is not signal safe, and we see it calling internal pthread mutex functions on some platforms:

```
0: c000000000436b90 : __ksleep() + 0x30 (/usr/lib/hpux64/libc.so.1)
1: c000000000152060 : __spin_lock_spin() + 0x1b0 (/usr/lib/hpux64/libpthread.so.1)
2: c0000000001d3da0 : __pth_bound() + 0x160 (/usr/lib/hpux64/libpthread.so.1)
3: c0000000001d9080 : __mxn_wakeup() + 0x140 (/usr/lib/hpux64/libpthread.so.1)
4: c0000000001429a0 : __pthread_mutex_unlock_ng() + 0x940 (/usr/lib/hpux64/libpthread.so.1)
5: c000000000142040 : pthread_mutex_unlock() + 0x20 (/usr/lib/hpux64/libpthread.so.1)
6: c000000000458370 : __thread_mutex_unlock() + 0xb0 (/usr/lib/hpux64/libc.so.1)
7: c000000000321cd0 : __localtime_r_posix() + 0x7e0 (/usr/lib/hpux64/libc.so.1)
```

We can dump the time safely by calling just `gettimeofday()` (omitting the "pretty-printing of the time with the followup `localtime_r()` call) and then post processing the stack trace file.  There are some difficulties with that idea, and it would be nice to avoid that if possible.

Without requiring post-processing outside of the signal handler, are there any known other ways to achieve a `localtime` like result that are signal safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a workaround for this problem.  Call `localtime`in a different thread for the process outside of a signal context and cache the value after clearing the hour/min/sec fields (along with the `mktime` result for that manipulated `struct tm`).

As long as I have a value from within the 24 hour period since the last cached value, I can consume it in the signal handler, manually constructing a `struct tm` for the `gettimeofday` in the handler by adding back in the hour/min/sec fields for the delta from the cached point in time.

It's not perfect, and there's some tricky aspects to ensuring I don't read a value that's being updated while the handler executes, but I can avoid post processing the post mortem dump file in most cases, and not trap or hang due to signal unsafe functions in the handler.